# Cordova inAppBrowser problems between platforms

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this code to open a browser on an Ionic App

```
<a href="#" class="button button-block"
       ng-click="register()">Registrarse</a>
```

And in the controller

```
$scope.register = function () {
        window.open('http://my.website.com/register', '_self', 'location:yes');
        return false;
    };
```

I tried with this too (after installing inAppBrowser plugin):

```
$scope.register = function () {
        $cordova.inappbrowser.open('http://my.website.com/register', '_self', 'location:yes');
        return false;
    };
```

It works in Android, but if I want this to run on iOS I need to install de Cordova inAppBrowser plugin.

The problem? When I install this plugin it works on iOS but not on Android :(

Are there any solution for this issue? I found a lot of "solutions" by searching on google, but without success...

Any idea will be highly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, both the code should work fine in both the platforms with minor behavioural changes. Not sure what is not working exactly?

Comment: I thought the same, but if I install `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` it works on iOS but not on Android and if I remove it `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`.... you can imagine what happens :(

Comment: could post any error trace? Thr question is still very abstract for me

Comment: Try to hook up your mobile phone to your computer, so you can see 'live' what's happening, which errors are being throwed. If you do, please provide your errors here so we can find a solution.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that because apparently there are no errors, at least while I run the app on iOS simulator and Android VM